# Client object identifier in BIND 9 query logs

Tags: bind

The BIND 9 Administrator Reference Manual e.g. for version [9.14.11](https://downloads.isc.org/isc/bind9/9.14.11/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.pdf) or [9.17.1](https://downloads.isc.org/isc/bind9/9.17.1/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.pdf) states in

- 5.2. CONFIGURATION FILE GRAMMAR

  - The `category` Phrase

    - `queries`

> The query log entry first reports a client object identifier in `@0x<hexadecimal-number>` format.

This term has not been mentioned anywhere else in the ARM, and it's the only mention of any *object identifier* at all.

- It seems not to be related to the client that was sending the query:

  - it could be the same for queries from many unrelated IP addresses but
  - it could be different for two queries from the same IP address.
- For e.g. `@0x123456789abc`

  - the first half `123456` seems always stay the same
  - the second half `789abc` changes from time to time.
- In query log examples it can be 32-bit `@0xffffffff` or 48-bit `@0xffffffffffff`.
- Alan Clegg, in this [BIND Logging](https://www.isc.org/docs/BIND_Logging.pdf) presentation from October 2019, only describes it through what it is not:

  > A `@0x` followed by the client object identifier (nothing to do with the client address)

**What is it and how is it calculated?**
What information can we get out of it?
Why is it logged anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Tony Finch's [reply](https://www.mail-archive.com/bind-users@lists.isc.org/msg27939.html) to bind-users mailing list in August 2019:

> It's the address in memory of the data structure BIND uses to hold its
>   working state for the query.

I'm surprised this seems the only place this is actually explained. The naming seems rather misleading as, based on this, it's not about the *client* nor *object identifiers* OID (per [ITU-T X.660](https://www.itu.int/itu-t/recommendations/rec.aspx?rec=X.660) | ISO/IEC 9834-1).

The explanation seems credible, as it's coherent with both the format and behaviour of the value. This logging comes from ISC's **[`lib/ns/client.c`](https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/-/blob/master/lib/ns/client.c#L2715) i.e. the *client object*** (*Thanks, Patrick Mevzek!*):

```
2715    isc_log_write(ns_lctx, category, module, level,
2716              "client @%p %s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s: %s", client, peerbuf, sep1,
2717              signer, sep2, qname, sep3, sep4, viewname, msgbuf);
```

**Here, the `%p` indeed is the memory address (pointer) of the `client`**, as it's written in C, and the `"client @%p %s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s: %s"` is a *printf format string*, where the [`%` placeholder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholder_specification) has:

> The syntax for a format placeholder is
>
> ```
> %[parameter][flags][width][.precision][length]type
> ```
>
> [Type field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Type_field)
>
> - `s`: null-terminated string.
> - `p`: `void *` (pointer to void) in an implementation-defined format.

Instead, the BIND 9 Administrator Reference Manual *COULD* simply say something like:

> The query log entry first reports the memory address of the data scructure used to hold the working state for the query, in `@0x<hexadecimal-number>` format.

Well, the whole paragraph could also be [formatted as a list](https://serverfault.com/a/1017475/274176) instead of a story...

Comment: I am not 100% sure but it may be that the log comes from https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/-/blob/master/lib/ns/client.c#L2704 ; it has `@%p` (a format that appears in a lot of other places), and it is a `client` variable injected to it, so indeed should yield a pointer to some structure allocated for the specific client handled there.

Comment: The `@` is just literally the character `@` on the string, and the `%p` refers to the pointer address as a placeholder in a *printf format string* in C. I've added this to my answer.